No puedo obtener el token JWT al iniciar la sesion (Spring Security)
Estoy haciendo un login pero a la hora de probar el endpoint de inicio de sesion en Postman, me indica el error 401 y en el codigo, lo configure para que a a la hora de iniciar sesion, me muestre el JWT generado pero no pasa nada (el endpoint de registro funciona correctamente y a la hora de testear en Postman, las credenciales son las correctas) si necesitan mas codigo para solucionar el problema, avisenme (mi teoria es que el problema esta en el securityFilterChain pero hasta ahora nada) la version de Spring es 3.2.5 y Spring Security es la 3.2.4
`public class KeyGeneratorUtility {
    public static KeyPair generateRsaKey() {
        KeyPair keyPair;
        
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            keyPair= keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        
        return keyPair;
        
    }
}
`
`@Component
public class RSAKeyProperties {
    public RSAPublicKey publicKey;
    public RSAPrivateKey privateKey;
    
    public RSAKeyProperties() {
        KeyPair pair = KeyGeneratorUtility.generateRsaKey();
        this.publicKey=(RSAPublicKey) pair.getPublic();
        this.privateKey=(RSAPrivateKey) pair.getPrivate();
    }

    public RSAPublicKey getPublicKey() {
        return publicKey;
    }

    public void setPublicKey(RSAPublicKey publicKey) {
        this.publicKey = publicKey;
    }

    public RSAPrivateKey getPrivateKey() {
        return privateKey;
    }

    public void setPrivateKey(RSAPrivateKey privateKey) {
        this.privateKey = privateKey;
    }
    
    
}
`
`
@Service
@Transactional
public class AuthenticationService {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    @Autowired 
    private TokenService tokenService;
    
    public ApplicationUser registerUser (String usuario, String contrasena) {
        String encodedPassword= passwordEncoder.encode(contrasena);
        Role userRole=roleRepository.findByAuthority("USER").get();
        
        Set<Role> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        authorities.add(userRole);
        
        return userRepository.save(new ApplicationUser(0, usuario, encodedPassword, authorities));
        
    }
    
    
    public LoginResponseDTO loginUser(String usuario, String contrasena) {
        try {
            Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(usuario, contrasena));
                    
            String token=tokenService.generateJwt(auth);
            
            return new LoginResponseDTO(userRepository.findByUsuario(usuario).get(), token);
        }catch(AuthenticationException e) {
            System.out.println("error en login");
            return new LoginResponseDTO(null, "");
        }
        
    }
`
`@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    
    private final RSAKeyProperties keys;
    
    public SecurityConfiguration(RSAKeyProperties keys) {
        this.keys=keys;
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authManager(UserDetailsService detailsService) {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoProvider= new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoProvider.setUserDetailsService(detailsService);
        return new ProviderManager(daoProvider);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
         http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        auth ->{
                            auth.requestMatchers("/auth/register").permitAll();
                            auth.requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN");
                            auth.requestMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER");
                             auth.requestMatchers("/auth/login").authenticated();
                            auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                        });
                        
                http.oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2
                        .jwt(jwtConfigurer-> jwtConfigurer.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter())));
                        /*posible problema aca
                        (oauth2) -> oauth2
                        .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults())
                        .jwt(jwtConfigurer-> jwtConfigurer.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter())))
                        *
                        */
                http.sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
                return http.build();
        
        /*por si da problemas: auth->{auth.requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll() PONERLO ARRIBA DEL AUTH.ANYREQUEST}*/
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(keys.getPublicKey()).build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JwtEncoder jwtEncoder() {
        JWK jwk = new RSAKey.Builder(keys.getPublicKey()).privateKey(keys.getPrivateKey()).build();
        JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwks = new ImmutableJWKSet<>(new JWKSet(jwk));
        
        return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwks);

    }
    
    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter= new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
        jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("roles");
        jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("ROLE_");
    
        JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter);
        return jwtConverter;
    }`@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class AuthenticationController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationService authenticationService;
    
    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ApplicationUser registerUser(@RequestBody RegistrationDTO body) {
        return authenticationService.registerUser(body.getUsuario(), body.getContrasena());
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public LoginResponseDTO loginUser(@RequestBody RegistrationDTO body) {
        return authenticationService.loginUser(body.getUsuario(), body.getContrasena());
    }
}
`@Service
public class TokenService {

    @Autowired
    private JwtEncoder jwtEncoder;
    
    @Autowired
    private JwtDecoder jwtDecoder;
    
    public String generateJwt(Authentication auth) {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        
        String scope=auth.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
        
        JwtClaimsSet claims= JwtClaimsSet.builder()
                .issuer("self")
                .issuedAt(now)
                .subject(auth.getName())
                .claim("roles", scope)
                .build();
        
        return jwtEncoder.encode(JwtEncoderParameters.from(claims)).getTokenValue();
        
    }`
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.springtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>springtoken</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springtoken</name>
    <description>login con token jwt</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>8.0.28</version>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>`


Probaste la configuración por defecto que requiere sólo un bean de tipo UserDetailService para la autentificación? En este ejemplo veo que pasa eso: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/blob/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/jwt/login/src/main/java/example/RestConfig.java

En el ejemplo en lugar de tener un servicio de autentificación sólo se crea un Bean en la configuración de tipo UserDetailService. Además en la SecurityFilterChain se agrega la llamada .csrf((csrf) -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers("/token")). La forma de loguearse sería un poco diferente, como se explica en el ejemplo los usuarios deberían primero autentificarse haciendo un solicitud post al endpoint /token.
